# Get data from tag html

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I wanna get data in the `<b>` tag, for example :

```
<b>
    <sup>1</sup>A, a
</b>
<b> ab </b>
<b><sup>2</sup>A</b>
```

I wanna get `A,a`, `ab` and `A` from tag above.

but sometimes there are no `<sup>` tag in line of data like below :

```
<b>ab</b>
```

but i wanna get data `ab`

I try to focus in `<b>` tag :

```
foreach($html->find('b') as $word) {
   $words = $word->innertext;
       echo $words.'<br>';}
```

But when there is `<sup>` tag, the text in the inside `<sup>` tag will be print too. How to not get the data inside `<sup>` tag? thank you

Comment: If there's no sup-tag, you don't get data from inside a sup-tag. If I understand your question correctly, you are trying something that is logically impossible. Unless there's some difference between `a` and `b`, which you didn't put into your question.

Comment: How do you know, which part of `ab` is normally in a `sup`-Tag?

Comment: Do you want to get A,a,ab   ???

Comment: @Salim yes, i wanna get A,a and ab

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text inside the parent element, i.e, `<b></b>` and ignoring `<sup></sup>` or any other element inside it by using [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

```
$('b')
.clone()      //clone the element
.children()   //select all childrens
.remove()     //remove all the children
.end()        //return to the matched element
.text();      //get the text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$html = "<b>
            <sup>1</sup>A, a
        </b>
        <b> ab </b>
        <b><sup>2</sup>A</b>";
//remove all html tags without <sup>
$html = strip_tags($html,"<sup>");
//remove <sup> tag with its content
$html = preg_replace('#\<sup>[{\w},\s\d"]+\</sup>#', "", $html);
//remove \t, \n and \r (tabs, newline etc)
$html = str_replace(array("\t","\n","\r"),"",$html);
//also you can remove space from string
$html = str_replace(" ","",$html);
echo $html;
?>
```